# How to use a radio button to select a list item in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to present my user with a list of package options, from which they select one.  I don't want to use a radio button list, as I need fairly complex templating for each list item.  Forgive me, but I just can't seem to figure out how to link a column of radio buttons to a selection property in my view model.

My view model has a `SelectedPackageId` (int), and a list of `MemberPackageListItem` view models that represent the individual packages.  `MemberPackageListItem` has a `PackageId` (int), so I need to couple the `PackageId` of the selected item to the `SelectedPackageId` of the root view model.

It is hard for me to post code, as inheritance etc. obscures much of what you would want to see, so I'm hoping my outline of a fairly common scenario, and some general guidelines on using radio buttons in this scenario will suffice to help me continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I appreciate the technical comprehensiveness of @counsellorben's answer, and will keep it around for future use, today I arrived at a more immediate and not altogether clumsy jQuery solution.  The selectors could be more specific, but I have no need now.  My solution is below.  Radio type inputs are grouped by their name attribute, which is given a different index for each row.  Therefore:

```
$(function () {
    // Back up current names of package radio buttons, then make all their names the same for grouping.
    $("#packageForm :radio[name$='.IsSelected']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("oldname", $(this).attr("name"));
    });
    $(":radio[name$='.IsSelected']").attr("name", "Package.IsSelected");

    // Hook the 'submit' click to restore original radio button names.
    $("#packageForm :submit").click(function () {
        $(":radio[name='Package.IsSelected']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("oldname", $(this).attr("name"));
        });
    });
});
```

IsSelected is my property per row that tells me if that row is selected, it isn't a jQuery or DOM property.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an HtmlHelper to render your radio button list, as follows:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TList, TSelectedItem>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TList>> expression,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TSelectedItem>> selectedItem)
    {
        return RadioButtonListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectedItem, null /* htmlAttributes */);
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TList, TSelectedItem>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TList>> expression, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TSelectedItem>> selectedItem, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return RadioButtonListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectedItem, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1006:DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures", Justification = "This is an appropriate nesting of generic types")]
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TList, TSelectedItem>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TList>> expression, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TSelectedItem>> selectedItem, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        }

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = null;
        if (metadata.Model != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> modelItems = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)metadata.Model;
            if (modelItems != null)
            {
                items = modelItems;
            }
        }

        ModelMetadata selectedItemMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(selectedItem, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        return RadioButtonListHelper(htmlHelper, metadata, selectedItemMetadata, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(selectedItem), items, htmlAttributes);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, 
        ModelMetadata selectedItemMetadata, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        // Verify arguments
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException("name", "Name cannot be null");
        if (selectList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selectList", "Select list cannot be null");
        if (selectList.Count() < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Select list must contain at least one value", "selectList");

        string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        string fullId = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "_" + name;

        IDictionary<string, object> validationAttributes = htmlHelper
            .GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(name), selectedItemMetadata);

        // Define items
        StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through items
        Int32 index = 0;
        foreach (SelectListItem i in selectList)
        {

            // Define check box input
            TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
            input.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
            input.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);
            if (i.Selected)
                input.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
            input.MergeAttribute("value", i.Value);
            if (index == 0)
                input.MergeAttributes(validationAttributes);
            input.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

            // Define label
            TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.MergeAttribute("for", fullId + "[" + index.ToString() + "].Selected");
            label.InnerHtml = i.Text;

            // Add item
            items.AppendFormat("\r\t<div>\r\t\t{0}\r\t\t{1}\r\t</div>",
                input.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal),
                label.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

            index++;
        }
        // Return list
        return new MvcHtmlString(items.ToString() + "\r");
    }
```

Please note that `MemberPackageListItem` must be of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.  Usage is as follows (Razor syntax):

```
    @Html.RadioButtonListFor(m => m.MemberPackageListItem, m => m.SelectedPackageId)
```

counsellorben